# Display text in a text box which is present inside a Web View

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

I am implementing my application for `iOS 7` in `xcode 5.`I use `navigationcontroller` to move from one `viewcontroller` to another. I have 2 `viewcontrollers` `ADMSViewController` which has webview overing the entire screen. When i click a link in the `webview`, `ADMSBarcodeScanner`  view controller is pushed to the top of the screen. After scanning the `ADMSBarcodeScanner` is popped from the top of the screen. Now the view controller that is currently displayed is `ADMSViewController`. I want to paste the scanned string to a text box inside the webview. I have written a javascript function to paste the string in the text box. Its called as

`iSetVinMobile("scanned string is the parameter")`

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a Java Script function from the native code using something like this:

```
[yourWebViewName stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iSetVinMobile("%@");",scannedString]];
```

Comment: Please provide a reply as per the question.

Comment: Doesn't the BarcodeScanner SDK your are using provide you a way of passing the scanned data to the viewcontroller who called it? If not, use NSNotificationCenter to pass the string from one viewController to the other or use delegates

Comment: i am able to pass data to the view controller which called it. I am able to paste it to a text box.